# Putting MathJax Base Code's in assets folder

Tags: android, mathjax

My app resource html's uses MathJax. So I need the MathJax Base codes.
I've put the codes in assets folder, so that html assets use it from Assets Folder. 
But this takes near 7-8 minutes to build/run the project is at need to do `:app:mergeDebugAssets` only which will take near 4 minutes.
It is taking near 3 minutes every time I run it. Is there any other way to do so that it will take less time ?

Comment: Depending on your requirements you can strip MathJax down considerably, see e.g. https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-grunt-cleaner

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger Already did that. But 17mb is still big enough.

Comment: On Android you shouldn't need more than 2-3MB. What are you leaving in?

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger 2-3 MB :O How?

Comment: I used another python program to minify that. How do I run the grunt file?

Comment: You'll need to install gruntjs, http://gruntjs.com.

Comment: But you can also do this manually, see old revisions of https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-docs/wiki/Guide%3A-reducing-size-of-a-mathjax-installation

Comment: Done :D .. Now 1.3 mb only 
Thanks :)

Comment: Btw, Is there any way without putting this in assets?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know Android development well.